# How to connect a Lan to L2 switch that can give internet access on a different subnet ? the set up is as shown in the figure

Tags: networking, router, switch

I need to set up my home network like in the diagram. I have a very basic understanding of networks, I'm unable to get the setup running, so was wondering if you could help with this.

I have a ftth modem/router(Alphion aont 1143) to which the ISP provides a static public ip MM.NN.OO.PP. I have set the dhcp server inside that router to a LAN private Ip range of 172.AA.BB.XX/24. The internet gateway for dhcp is the router address 172.AA.BB.CC/24. From a LAN port of the router, the router is connected to a port on the switch,DGS 3000 10TC, by an ethernet cable.There is a PC connected to one of the remaining ports of the switch , this PC should get the IP Subnet 10.XX.YY.ZZ/24 and internet access. How to achieve this?

1)The router is not Vlan aware, can the above setup be achieved without VLans?
2) the router does not allow port forwarding to a different subnet and has no NAT options 3) the switch does not support interVlan routing but has other L3 functionality like : Support 1024 ARP Entries ,Gratuitous ARP, Default Route. I'm not sure if any of these would be helpful
4) What should be the static route / default gateway /ACL? I tried to set these in the switch but it didn't work, so i'm not sure even if I did it right.

[image: router to switch network setup]

Comment: Why not just set the entire LAN on 10.XX.YY.0/24 network and be done with it?  If your router wont let you add a second LAN IP address you would need to replace or supplement it with additional hardware to do otherwise.

Comment: @davidgo I have a set of servers on the 172 subnet , an want to separate the network for another set of systems on 10 subnet. Is it possible anyway without adding another router inbetween, as i cannot buy another one? Any idea how to give static route for the router in this set up?

Comment: I dont know that router. You dont need to add a static route - you need to add a second interface on the router in the 10.XX.YY.0/24 range - that will have the affect of updating the routing table and making everything work.